# How to convert 0 (and only 0) into my data structure

Tags: c++, types, typeconverter

I am implementing a SI unit type system. To ensure units don't leak in and out, I don't want implicit conversion of any values to a unit, and vice-versa. However, it would be really convenient to be able convert 0 to my unit system, a bit like you can do with pointers, where 0 implicitly converts to a null pointer, but no other value does.

So my question is: can I replicate this kind of implicit conversion of 0 to null pointer? Or can I use it to my advantage to achieve the same thing?

For example what would you think of such a constructor?

```
constexpr unit_t(void*) : _value(0) { }
```

Note: the unit itself is in the type, not in the value.

**Edit: Why casting from 0 to a unit?**

The reason I want this, is to write algorithms that don't know about units. For example, if you have a matrix of lengths and you want to invert it, you first compute its determinant, and if it's not 0, then return the inverse (otherwise, this is an error).

So it would convenient to treat the 0 literal as a generic unit. And this is exactly what happens for pointers. You can type:

```
void* c = 0;
```

But not:

```
void f(int a) { void *c = a; }
```

Comment: `constexpr` is part of C++11, so are other C++11 features also available? If so, what about `nullptr_t`?

Comment: Options: 1. static_assert on constexpr argument (dunno if it works, bit clunky) 2. nullptr (no, don't use that) 3. UDL, so you use 0Z instead of just 0, possibly with static_assert (though if there's only one possible value then it's still clunky) 4. `struct zero_t {}; static constexpr zero_t zero;` and implicit constructor and don't use `0` literal at all.

Comment: Could you please give us a reason why "casting" 0 to a different unit would be desirable? I mean, just because a value is 0 doesn't mean it suddenly lost its unit. It would be dangerous to just shed the unit, even when value is 0.

Comment: I would implement a `Zero` type and provide a special constructors taking it as argument.

Comment: In your matrix example, it sounds as though you just need more genericness. If you write a function `template <typename T> Matrix<T> inverse(Matrix<T>);`, then when you want a unitful zero, you use `T(0)`. But anyway isn't the determinant of a matrix unitless? I don't think you should have a *matrix* of lengths and compute its determinant, you should have a unitless *matrix* that you multiply together with a *vector* of lengths, to yield another vector of lengths. If the matrix itself has units, then the product of two matrices has the square of those units, which IME isn't what you want.

Comment: @SteveJessop Actually, the determinant of a matrix has a dimension. If you work with a unit [u] the determinant of a NxN matrix is [u^N]. Also, matrix can have a unit, for example if they represent rank 2 tensors.

Comment: @PierreBdR: ah OK, so without this special zero-conversion, the value you want to compare with is something verbose like `typename unit_to_the_power_of<T,N>::type(0)`. I see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical solution is to a pointer to some private type, that the user can't name.  That way, the only way he can get something that will match is through the implicit conversion from `0`.  (Using `void*` means that practically anything which can convert to a pointer can be passed.)

Note that this solution only works for *integral* constant 0.  If the user wants to use `0.0` (because he thinks that `double` values make more sense), he can't.

You might also consider using a default constructor, so the client can simply write `SomeUnit()` when he wants the default initialization.